# Python pandas convert single value in object column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Solved Below**

**Issue:** Cannot `.groupby()` sort because a single value is a `string` type object. The value at `Index 5`, `ColA 10` for `Data In` is the issue. The value at `Index 5` for `ColA`, `10`, is a string object. `pd.to_numeric()` properly sorts the column if only sorted by that column.

**Question:** Can a single value in `ColA` be converted?

**Method:**

```
ind = pd.to_numeric(df['ColA'], errors='coerce').fillna(999).astype(int).argsort()
df = df.reindex(ind)
df = df.groupby(df.ColA).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'ColB')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Data in:**

```
Index     ColA     ColB     ColC
0         2        14-5     MumboJumbo
1         4        18-2     MumboJumbo2
2         2        24-5     MumboJumbo3
3         3        23-8     MumboJumbo4
4         2        13-6     MumboJumbo5
5         10       86-1     MumboJumbo6
6         10       42-1     MumboJumbo7
7         2        35-6     MumboJumbo8
8         Load     NaN      MumboJumbo9
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Index     ColA     ColB     ColC
0         2        13-6     MumboJumbo5
1         2        14-5     MumboJumbo
2         2        24-5     MumboJumbo3
3         2        35-6     MumboJumbo8
4         3        23-8     MumboJumbo4
5         4        18-2     MumboJumbo2
6         10       42-1     MumboJumbo7
7         10       86-1     MumboJumbo6
8         Load     NaN      MumboJumbo9
```

Thanks!

Comment: The bigger issue here isn't the string in `ColA`, it's the strings in `ColB` that need to be sorted by the numbers they contain

Comment: Those sort fine. There is zero issue when sorting `ColB` using `.groupby()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem in the question but you can select specific values in a `DataFrame` using `iloc` (positional index) or `loc` (label index). Since you are asking to replace the value in the fifth row in the first column in your dataset, we use `iloc`.

```
df.iloc[from_row:to_row,column_position]
```

To convert value `'10'` in `ColA` at row 5 to an `int('10')` you simply select it and then update it.

```
df.iloc[5:6,0] = 10
```

---

If you don't know the location of the value you need to convert, then `iloc` and `loc` is no help.

There are several ways to convert all values in a column to a specific `dtype`. One way would be using a `lambda`-function.

```
df[column_name].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

The `lambda` above will break because your data also contains the string `Load` and you can't convert that to an `int`. One way to solve this is adding conditions to your `lambda`.

```
df[column_name].apply(lambda x: int(x) if something else something)
```

Given the data in your question the most straightforward way would be to check if `x` is not `'Load'`:

```
df[column_name].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x != 'Load' else x)
```

This becomes a hassle if you have loads of actual strings in your column. If you want to use a `lambda` you could make a list of the actual strings. And then check if `x` is in the list.

```
list_of_strings = ['Load', 'Road', 'Toad']
df[column_name].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x not in list_of_strings else x)
```

Another way would be to write a separate function to manage the converting using try/catch blocks.

Comment: How would you change `iloc` to account for this bad value moving around in the column? It may not always be Index 5.

Comment: Do you need to keep `'Load'` in `ColA` and if so, is `'Load'` always followed by `NaN` in `ColB`?

Comment: Yes `Load` needs to stay in `ColA` because it is an identifier in A. The database is not setup how I would prefer but the way it pulls in information requires it be in that column.

Yes it will always be followed by NaN in ColB. `Load` may not always be present, and it may be a variety of 3-4 different strings. I think your lamba solution is closest to working. I can build that list very easily, I think max there are 4 options it may be.  I'm going to try now.

Comment: `df['ColA'] = df['ColA'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x not in list_of_strings else x)`
works!